# How open facebook and twitter on a specific page in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, url, twitter

Which is the line of code to open facebook and twitter displaying a given page?

tried with this for Facebook

`NSURL *target = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"fb://profile/WindyCityCrossFit"];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:target];`

but it just taks me to my news feed page. Twitter haven't given me any results either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook:

`NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://profile/130936560286785"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];`

Twitter:

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"twitter://user?screen_name=MyTwitterID"]];`

Comment: Yes sorry, my apologies. You need to be using the UID of the page you are trying to show. Find this UID by looking at the source code of the page.

Comment: I have just updated my post with the UID (130936560286785) of the facebook page from your original post

Comment: And is there no way that just using the web address or something simpler could this be accomplished. The deal is that the app should allow the user to link their gym's facebook twitter page so anybody could see it once uploaded. But seems like a too much complex procedure for the user to go into the source code.

Comment: Although not exactly easy, this is by far the simplest way to implement what OP was asking for

Comment: What do either of these URLs do if the user doesn't have the twitter or facebook apps installed?

Answer (score 0):

This should get you to facebook, though I'm not sure about twitter.

```
NSString *urlString = <your url>;
NSString *title = <your message>;
NSString *shareUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=%@&t=%@", urlString , title];
shareUrlString = [shareUrlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:shareUrlString];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Comment: what does the title and the urlstring variable stand for?

Comment: This is if you wanted to open someone's facebook with an auto-generated post linking to your URL. So, it doesn't exactly answer the question-- oops.